# SBT's dependsOn is not adding all transitive projects to classpath

Tags: sbt

transitive dependency resolution for dependsOn is not working as I would expect.

Setup:

```
lazy val myutil = project
lazy val myapi = project.dependsOn(myutil)
lazy val myapp = project.dependsOn(myapi)
```

Expectation:

> When building myapp, I expect sbt to put both myapi and myutil projects on the classpath.

Reality:

> When building myapp, sbt places the myapi project on the classpath
>   but then tries to pull myutil from a repository.  This fails.

Workaround:

```
lazy val myapp = project.dependsOn(myapi, myutil)
```

this workaround ends up putting both myapi and myutil projects on the classpath, but the need to do this seems counter to automatic transitive dependency resolution.

Has anyone been able to get dependsOn to work with transtive subproject dependencies without having to list all of transitive projects explicitly?